# Wildcard .htaccess rewrite subdomain to a subdirectory with subdomain as GET variable

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Sample Urls:

```
http://username1.example.com/inventory/
http://username2.example.com/profile/about
http://example.com/products/category/
```

Rewrite to:

```
http://example.com/subdomains/inventory/?user=username1
http://example.com/subdomains/profile/about?user=username2
http://example.com/products/category/
```

I think I have searched most of the internet for this.

How do I rewrite the path by adding "subdomains" folder immediately after the domain and pass the subdomain as GET variable to access it via PHP? There shouldn't be any change in the url which the user can see in this address bar.
There shouldn't be any change or rewrite when there is no sub domain.

Right now, I can get both path and sub domain as GET variables like below but that is not what I want.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www\.)[^.]+)\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*\.(jpg|css|js|gif|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?subdomain=%1&request=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Please consider that I am a .htaccess noob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (if you already have some other rewrite rules, put these on top):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www\.)[^.]+)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com/subdomains%{REQUEST_URI}?user=%1 [QSA,L,P]
```

Comment: The above code is rewriting `http://abc.example.com` to `http://example.com/subdomains/subdomains/?user=abc`. I am not sure what caused the additional `/subdomains/`. If we can remove the additional `/subdomains/`, everything would be perfect. You can see the implementation at [link](http://abc.toours.com/) @DusanBajic

Comment: When I remove the `[p]` flag, everything is working fine but the url in user's browser is also changing. @dusan

Comment: Adding the following below your two lines of code does the job but I do not know how.
`RewriteRule (.*)/subdomains/(.*) $1/$2`
Is there a mod_rewrite tutorial for dummys?

Comment: :) yes, there is one: http://serverfault.com/questions/214512/redirect-change-urls-or-redirect-http-to-https-in-apache-everything-you-ever?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Anyway, that line does fix it allright, but does not explain how the second /subdomains got there. And I can not reproduce it on my test server. Is there perhaps some other Rule that could have added it?

Comment: There are no other rewrite rules except these three lines. @dusan

Comment: Sorry for the really late response. I have been using your code all this time. Now, I want to redirect all my traffic to https://.
http://username1.example.com/subdir/ 
should rewrite to 
https://example.com/subdomains/subdir/?user=username1
How do I do this? There is no other code in my .htaccess other than your code. @DusanBajic