# Wildcard .htaccess rewrite subdomain and whitelabel domain as GET variable

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

To start off, I am not strong with rewrite rules. I already went through 
[Wildcard .htaccess rewrite subdomian to a subdirectory with subdomain as GET variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38713867/) (My question) and [.htaccess rewrite: subdomain as GET parameter and filepath afterdomain intact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25389032/) and https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/ but I couldn't find the solution to my problem. I am also not sure if my requirement is possible but I am still asking to make sure.
Desired result:

```
http://example.com             -> https://www.example.com             [redirect]
http://example.com/dir/?key=12 -> https://www.example.com/dir/?key=12 [redirect]
https://example.com            -> https://www.example.com             [redirect]
https://example.com/dir/?key=12 -> https://www.example.com/dir/?key=12 [redirect]
http://xyz.example.com         -> https://xyz.example.com             [redirect]
http://www.xyz.example.com     -> https://xyz.example.com             [redirect]
https://www.xyz.example.com    -> https://xyz.example.com             [redirect]
https://xyz.example.com        -> https://www.example.com/whitelabel/?user=xyz [proxy]
https://xyz.example.com/profile.php -> https://www.example.com/whitelabel/profile.php?user=xyz            [proxy]
https://xyz.example.com/dir/settings.php -> https://www.example.com/whitelabel/dir/settings.php?user=xyz  [proxy]
https://xyz.example.com/dir/settings.php?par=val -> https://www.example.com/whitelabel/dir/settings.php?user=xyz&par=val [proxy]
http://example.org             -> https://www.example.com/whitelabel/?domain=abc.example.org              [proxy]
https://www.example.org        -> https://www.example.com/whitelabel/?domain=example.org                  [proxy]
https://example.org?param=val  -> https://www.example.com/whitelabel/?domain=example.org&param=val        [proxy]
https://example.org/dir1/dir2?param=val -> https://www.example.com/whitelabel/dir1/dir2?domain=example.org&param=val [proxy]
```

Why do I need this? Every registered user gets a sub domain by default but if he has a domain, he can point that domain to my dedicated IP. I have to show different content to each subdomain or domain.
I already did the http->https and adding www where required. I also passed subdomain as GET parameter. Each code works fine individually but they are not working when combined. Maybe, it has something to do with the order of the rules. Anyways, here is my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www\.)[^.]+)\.toours\.com$
RewriteRule ^ https://www.toours.com/whitelabel%{REQUEST_URI}?user=%1 [QSA,L,P]
RewriteRule (.*)/whitelabel/(.*) $1/$2 [L]
</IfModule>
```

This just gives an internal server error.

Comment: Comment out `RewriteRule (.*)/whitelabel/(.*) $1/$2 [L]` line and retest.

Comment: still the same error. Thanks for joining in @anubhava. I was thinking of contacting you via linked in for this. Your reputation precedes you.

Comment: Thanks. You should check Apache error.log to see why 500 is coming at this point.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you most of the way

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

# ensure www when no subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule .* https://www.%0/$0 [L,R=301]
# ensure no www when user subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.([^.]+\.example\.com)$
RewriteRule .* https://%1/$0 [L,R=301]
# ensure https for all (you will have to add users' own domains to your SSL cert)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$0 [L,R=301]

# set env vars if user subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)([^.]+)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ - [E=USERID:%1,E=USERPARAM:user]
# set env vars if user own domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.+(?<!\.example\.com)$
RewriteRule ^ - [E=USERID:%0,E=USERPARAM:domain]

# user main page pretty URLs (removed ".php" from the public URLs)
RewriteCond %{ENV:USERID} .+
RewriteRule ^$ whitelabel/?%{ENV:USERPARAM}=%0 [L,B,QSA]
RewriteCond %{ENV:USERID} .+
RewriteRule ^profile$ whitelabel/profile.php?%{ENV:USERPARAM}=%0 [L,B,QSA]
RewriteCond %{ENV:USERID} .+
RewriteRule ^dir/settings$ whitelabel/dir/settings.php?%{ENV:USERPARAM}=%0 [L,B,QSA]
RewriteCond %{ENV:USERID} .+
# put any other whitelabel rules before this, so any remaining URLs that are not on your main domain get a custom 404 page
RewriteRule ^ whitelabel/dir/404.php?%{ENV:USERPARAM}=%0 [L,B,QSA]

# place any other pretty URLs for main domain here, probably rewrite all non-file requests to a single file and route from there
</IfModule>
```

Query strings will be appended by default where the substitution hasn't got one, and I've added `QSA` where it has.

Not sure what to do about redirecting to canonical user-owned domains.